# loops in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have written a SP that is working as expected. It will return the customer ID and monthly and annual fees he should be charged.

Now what I want to do is to insert the relevant records in various other tables. Is it possible to use a transaction within stored procedure?
How do I take one record at a time and insert into other tables?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a transaction within stored procedure?

++ Yes it is. You may read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

How do I take one record at a time and insert into other tables?

++ Perhaps using [INSERT INTO SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html), one insert per table.